how to add authorizer for a aws serverless NodeJS application
I have created the nodejs rest api using serverless framework. The application is very similar to the below template. I have created a custom authentication as a separate service i want include that authorizer in this application. I am getting syntax error and I am not able to find example on how to use authorizer while working with httpApi
service: aws-node-express-api

frameworkVersion: "4"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs20.x

functions:
  api:
    handler: handler.handler
    events:
      - httpApi: "*"

If we use http event we can easily add like below
  privateEndpoint:
    handler: handler.privateEndpoint
    events:
      - http:
          path: api/private
          method: post
          authorizer: auth
          cors: true

https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/11ca3bd4bf13af6b48bb715608357d1f3b01caaf/aws-node-express-api

The absolute golden stack overflow rule for asking a question about an error, is to include that error in your question. The full error, verbatim with all the trimmings.

The link you included in your post will lead you to the documentation on how to configure authorizers for the HTTP API.
